# Call parent function which is being overridden by child during constructor chain in JavaScript(ES6)

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, this, ecmascript-6

I've encounter a problem below with JavaScript(ES6)

```
class A{
  constructor(){
    this.foo();
  }
  foo(){
    console.log("foo in A is called");
  }
}

class B extends A{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.foo();
  }
  foo(){
    console.log("foo in B is called");
  }
}
```

What I expect is

```
foo in A is called
foo in B is called
```

But actually it is

```
foo in B is called
foo in B is called
```

I know I can resolve this by simply adding `super.foo()` in class B's foo function

```
class B extends A{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.foo();
  }
  foo(){
    super.foo() // add this line
    console.log("foo in B is called");
  }
}
```

But imagine a scenario similar to this:

Child has to override parent's function in order to do some extra works and prevent access from outer being able to access to the original one.

```
class B extends A{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.initBar();
  }
  foo(){
    super.foo();
    this.bar.run(); //undefined
    console.log("foo in B is called");
  }
  initBar(){
    this.bar.run = function(){
      console.log("bar is running");
    };
  }
}
```

It seems that `this` still points to child `B` while constructing in parent `A`. That's why I can't reach parent `A`'s `foo`.

How do I make `this` to call parent version function which is being overridden by child during constructor chain?

Or is there any better solution when it comes to scenario like this?

**Edit**

So, after reading answers, the main question becomes --

**Is it discouraged to put `initialize helpers` or `setter functions` in constructor in JavaScript since children have a chance to override them?**

To clarify the situation more clearly: (sorry for my previous bad example :( )

```
class A{
  constructor(name){
    this.setName(name);
  }
  setName(name){
    this._name = name;
  }
}

class B extends A{
  constructor(name){
    super(name);
    this._div = document.createElementById("div");
  }
  setName(name){
    super.setName(name);
    this._div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  }
}

new B("foo")
```

`this._div` will be `undefined`.

Is this a bad idea since child will be able to override the function?

```
class A{
  constructor(name){
    this.setName(name); // Is it bad?
  }
  ...
}
```

So I shouldn't use `initialize helpers` or `setter functions` in constructor like in Java, C++...?

Must I manually call things like this `new A().init()` to help me initialize things?

Comment: *How do I make `this` to call parent version function* - `super` is the only way.

Comment: Why does the `A` constructor call `this.foo()` at all? It should not, it should only initialise the instance.

Comment: Is the child `foo` meant to override the parent implementation in the general cause, or are you more asking how to make "foo" some private helper?

Comment: ES6 class syntax is still generating a prototype just like we used to hand code.  So, when you define `foo` in class B, it is still overriding the definition of `foo` on the prototype and this `this.foo()` no matter where you call it will refer to the class B definition.  As you seem to already know, if you want to call the class A version of foo, you have to do that manually.

Comment: FYI, you seem to think there are two objects, one for child and one for parent.  That is not the way it works.  `this` doesn't point to child B.  `this` points to the entire object, of which both A and B have properties on the instance and methods on the prototype.  There is only one object with both A and B contributing properties and methods.  That's why there's only one `this` too and why `this.foo` points to the most recent override.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that you should get exactly the same result with equivalent code in Java, Python, and C++.

Answer (score 18):

You seem to be operating under a misconception that there are two objects `A` and `B` when you are in the constructor of the derived class `B`.  This is not the case at all. There is one and only one object.  Both `A` and `B` contribute properties and methods to that one object.  The value of `this` will be the same in the constructor for `B` as it is in the constructor for `A` during the creation of an object of class B.

The ES6 class syntax is just sugar over the ES5 method of using prototypes for object types and, in fact, the prototype is still used under the covers.  As such, when you define a method `foo` in a derived class like you do in class B, it is still assigning to the prototype and that assignment overrides any method of the same name that might already exist on the prototype that came from the parent definition.  This is why `this.foo()` refers to the class B version of `foo`.  If you want to reach the class A version of `foo`, then you will have manually specify that using `super` as you appear to already know.

As for your specific questions:

> It seems that this still points to child B while constructing in
>   parent A. That's why I can't reach parent A's foo.

child B and parent A are not separate objects.  There is one object that both parent A and child B reference.  parent A and child B methods or constructors will see the exact same value of `this`.

> How do I make this to call parent version function which is being
>   overridden by child during constructor chain?

You use `super` to reference parent methods directly as you appear to already know.

> Or is there any better solution when it comes to scenario like this?

`super` is the solution.

---

FYI, this is a pretty good discussion on ES6 classes including how `super` works: [Classes in ECMAScript 6 (final semantics)](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#referring_to_super-properties_in_methods).  Section 4.4 seems particularly relevant to your question/understanding.

Comment: I think it is better not to use setters in the parent constructor like "this.setName(name);" and it will be better to use this.name = name; like this when you use super() you will not use override functions you are not aware to.