# How to override react component lifecycle methods

Tags: reactjs

I would like to override react component lifecycles (like *shouldComponentUpdate*) and call the default ones if necessary. I tried  starting with something like:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return super.shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState);
}
```

But it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you transpiling your code? This works for me when I use babel with the correct es6 transforms + polyfill. Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615034/call-parent-function-which-is-being-overridden-by-child-during-constructor-chain

Comment: as docs say https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#overview React.Component is an abstract class so there is no default implementation available. You need to define it in your components.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is write es7 decorator, you can write somethink like this:

```
function shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  //your custom shouldComponentUpdate function
}

function customShouldComponentUpdate(component) {
  component.prototype.shouldComponentUpdate = shouldComponentUpdate;
  return component;
}
```

Thanks this decorator you can override method `shouldComponentUpdate` in react component.

usage example:

```
@customShouldComponentUpdate
class Foo extends Component{
  //code
}
```